# Salesforce Flow not validating blank fields

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to validate two date fields in a Salesforce screen flow using the following formula:

AND(
ISBLANK(Resolution_Date),ISBLANK(Still_Sick_Date)
)

This formula is simply checking if both date fields are blank, but for some reason my flow won't validate blank fields. I read on the Salesforce [Ideaexchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdjJKUAZ/screen-flow-validate-on-blank-text-field) that this may be a Salesforce limitation but I wanted to get some other opinions and see if anyone has found a workaround.

My expected outcome with using the formula is have an error message thrown when both date fields are null.